# How can I hide a link's origin from the linked-to site's analytics?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I've been googling for a while now, but wasn't able to find an answer to this.

What I want to accomplish is the following:

Let's say I have a website that I hide from search engines etc. and that is pretty much only accessible through the direct URL. I want only people whom I send the link to see the site.

On my site I talk about my favourite pizza and link to *Joe's Pizza Store*.

When one of my visitor clicks the link, *Joe's Pizza Store* will see my URL as a referrer in their analytics.

Is there anything I can do to my link tags (or otherwise) to obscure the origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `rel="noreferrer"`

something like this:

```
<a href="signin.php" rel="noreferrer">sign in</a>
```

> The noreferrer keyword may be used with a and area elements. This
>   keyword does not create a hyperlink, but annotates any other
>   hyperlinks created by the element (the implied hyperlink, if no other
>   keywords create one).
>
> It indicates that no referrer information is to be leaked when
>   following the link.
>
> If a user agent follows a link defined by an a or area element that
>   has the noreferrer keyword, the user agent must not include a Referer
>   (sic) HTTP header (or equivalent for other protocols) in the request.
>
> This keyword also causes the opener attribute to remain null if the
>   hyperlink creates a new browsing context.

More info [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#link-type-noreferrer)