# How to hide the link/click origin?

Tags: html, hyperlink, http-referer

I have a website with promotional content. Let's call it website A. On this website, I give a URL to an advertiser website where people are buying something. Let's call it website B.

If I use `rel="noreferrer"` (like here: [How can I hide a link's origin from the linked-to site's analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38223068/how-can-i-hide-a-links-origin-from-the-linked-to-sites-analytics)), is it possible for the owner of website B to find out where does the traffic come from?

I want to hide the origin of the users so I am secured.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for the owner of site B to find out where the traffic comes from.

> Readers can click on the links, but the destination site will not see that they came from your site.

[Source](https://www.thoughtco.com/rel-noreferrer-3468002)

You can also use HTTPS, which will not send any referral information.

In summary, you're secure.